QML TestCase not triggering with my component: What am I missing?
I created a component and decided to immediately add a TestCase to it to check when the application is launched, but the application does not start and even more so does not run.
My file is called SomeComponentsTest.qml
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtTest 1.2

Rectangle {
    id: root

    color: "yellow"
    width: 200
    height: 200
    radius: 5

    signal clicked

    property int value: 0

    onClicked: {
        root.value++;
    }

    Label {
        id: label
        objectName: "label"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font.pixelSize: 24
        color: "black"
        text: root.value;
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        objectName: "mouseArea"
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked: {
            root.clicked();
        }
    }

    TestCase {
        name: "SomeComponentTests"

        function test_color() {
            compare(root.color, "yellow")
            root.color = "#008000";
            compare(root.color, "#008000")
        }

        function test_size() {
            compare(root.width, 200)
            compare(root.height, 200)
        }

        function test_label() {
            compare(label.font.pixelSize, 24);
            label.font.pixelSize = 44;
            compare(label.font.pixelSize, 44);
        }
    }
}

Yes, I know that for tests the prefix should be tst_*.qml
But I have a dissonance in my head when I read the documentation, there is such an example:
Rectangle {
    width: 640; height: 480

    MultiPointTouchArea {
        id: area
        anchors.fill: parent

        property bool touched: false

        onPressed: touched = true
    }

    TestCase {
        name: "ItemTests"
        when: windowShown
        id: test1

        function test_touch() {
            let touch = touchEvent(area);
            touch.press(0, area, 10, 10);
            touch.commit();
            verify(area.touched);
        }
    }
}

where for some reason a Rectangle is created before TestCase and I suppose that it is still possible to somehow run TestCase without the tst_*.qml prefix.
Do you know anything about this?

I think there is a misunderstanding here. Yes, Rectangle in the example is parent item for TestCase. This is possible. But all files with Qt Quick test cases must have a name starting from "tst_". And the example with Rectangle doesn't state any file name.
